# How to save Image that is captured from windows phone automatically after click save button in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have 3 buttons and 1 image view. The first button(Camera) opens camera and clicks image and set the clicked image into that image view. 2nd button(File) pic the image from the folder and I want my third button(Save) to save that displayed image into mobile. In desktop, I can easily use file picker option to store the image in respected folder but I want the image to be saved automatically after pressing that button in the mobile gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample on [code.msdn](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Capturing-Image-Using-098f68bb).
Rather than display the contents of the first storage file and then create a new one to save the file I just combined the  code samples with a randomly generated filename in the pictures folder (remember to add the pictures folder capability.)

```
private StorageFile storeFile;
private IRandomAccessStream stream;
private async void SavePhotoClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CameraCaptureUI capture = new CameraCaptureUI();
        capture.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
        capture.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(3, 5);
        capture.PhotoSettings.MaxResolution = CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution.HighestAvailable;
        storeFile = await capture.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

        if (storeFile != null)
        {
            stream = await storeFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

            var s = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg");

            using (var dataReader = new DataReader(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0)))
            {
                await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)stream.Size];
                dataReader.ReadBytes(buffer);

                await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(s, buffer);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(ex.Message, "Unable to save now.");
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing my own answer, I though since you pointed out to proper sample page, it would be better to edit your answer and include the piece of code what OP is looking for. Hope this is OK with you.

Comment: @Matt Lacey the code you have written doesn't meed my requirement. I requested that the picture should automatically be saved in mobile phones without asking for path.

Comment: @BibeshManandhar updated answer based on revising the linked sample code

Comment: @MattLacey One last request. Can you help me saving that picture in a folder, creating the folder if not exists. like that ?

Comment: @BibeshManandhar don't ask new questions in comments. Ask a new question. (There isn't space to answer such in a comment anyway.) see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers